# How to use a PTC heater to heat water?

Tags: ptc

I have a very specific need to manage the temperature of a small tub of water (about 500 ml) to a very specific heat curve over the course of a few weeks, so I am thinking of building a simple Arduino circuit to help me do this.

For slowly heating the water, I bought a [PTC heater](https://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/product/B07NL8YFH4/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_image_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&th=1) off Amazon, which I have never used. It came basically with no instructions, so for people who have used these heaters, I have a few questions:

- The item description says it works at 12V DC. How accurate does this need to be? Is it acceptable to under/over power it by one or two volts?
- Does this thing have any polarity to it? Both wires coming out from it are black, so I don't know which wire should be positive and which one negative.
- This device has a very low resistance. Do I need to use a current limiting resistor? Or do I just hook it up to the power source?
- If I'm going to use two of these should I put them in series or in parallel?
- Are these things waterproof? Can I just dump it into the tub of water? Or should I be mounting them outside of the water? I'll be leaving it inside for weeks to months.

Comment: If you look at other product listings that look very similar, you'll find that some of them mention it cannot be immersed in water.

Comment: You might be looking for an immersion heater of the type used for kettles or for aquariums.

Comment: @DamienD: Good idea. However, the ones I'm looking at are all AC, and quite big. I'll probably heat the tub from the outside then...

Answer (score 2):

There are three different devices to choose from on that Amazon listing.
176°F (80°C): 2W - 5W

110°C: 3W - 10W

220°C: 5W - 28W

The high wattage is the power output at room temp and the higher wattage is the output at the temperature listed. You will still need a temp sensor snd control from the Arduino but the lower power near your set point temp means it is easier to control an exact temp without overshoot.

If you want to add additional units, connect in parallel.

It is not clear if you can submerge them.

No polarity.

You'll need a relay module or a MOSFEt to control this with an Arduino. An Arduino cannot directly output that much power.

The 12v is approximate in most cases. The more stabile the voltage, the more easily you can control the voltage with On/off threshold settings.  If you have varying airflow or room temps, you can look into PID algorithms.

You will need to insulate the bath because the lower power listing is not much and you'll lose that much heat to surroundings without insulation or you'll need multiple heaters.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I will be using a temperature monitor (hence the entire point of using arduino), and powering them through relays. I am also insulating the tub with aluminum foil, so the question remaining is if I can just put it directly in water, because if not, the complexity of the build goes up. Also, what about limiting the current? By the way, I got the 80C one, since the target temperatures are around 30C.